# What's the effect of living on alms (social services) and not doing duties, being unrestrained?

Tags: rebirth, virtue, community

Would it be similar like the destiny for monks?

It's said that one living on alms, not doing his duties (foremost sense-restrain) but enjoys sensual pleasures increases his debts: e.g. poorness, strong dependend, low states.

And those without metta and virtue, fall under the category of thieves.

Do those solcial-consumer, relaying even on alms not even given for the liberating practice, not maybe even steal or misuse from both communities and thereby head toward much pain, generate toward real outcasts everywhere?

Comment: What does this mean? The question is not clear.

Comment: @ruben2020 My guess was that the question refers to someone who is interested in Buddhism, perhaps who posts online, who don't hold down a job for some reason (and subsists on social securoity instead), and yet who don't go forth. But it asks about their destiny so it might be hard to answer authoritatively. It may also beg the question of what their "duty" is if they do receive social security and have not joined the sangha.

Comment: You cannot equate alms with social services, they have nothing in common. Is this a question about how karma works?

Answer (score -1):

It's very common that "state-children", living on social care by state or charity, lazy to work and contribute, seek "refuge" in "I am a Buddhist", worthy of gifts, and on that, relay on both communities, yet neither do their duties here nor there, being not only material but also "spiritual" consumer. Commonly they of course don't care about family either.

Nothing else as states of hungry ghost, orphan animal, or hell can be expected, after breaking off of this body. If gaining human existance, such are born as poor orphans, slaves, group-confused, lack of any social state, refugees, anonymous, haunted consumer without relation, heirs: fearful real outcasts, beggars among monastery lanes.

Take care and know your duties and dependency well, instead of hoping "I have a right" will pay off the debt!